# Request redirecting when running a flow in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have recorded a script in JMeter, when I run it in view result tree URL gets changed automatically to some other page. My original request has no cookies while the page to which it redirects contain cookies. Later , I checked manually in my browser I saw cookies passing in the request. So, I added HTTP header manager with cookie data , I executed the test still it is redirecting. I thought to correlate cookie value but I can't get it in any response above. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Have you added "HTTP Cookie Manager"?

Comment: Have checked follow-redirects on http request sampler?